# Confused about Type Erase and Bridge Methods

Tags: java, generics

The Java™ Tutorials
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bridgeMethods.html
shows an example:

```
public class Node<T> {

    public T data;

    public Node(T data) { this.data = data; }

    public void setData(T data) {
        System.out.println("Node.setData");
        this.data = data;
    }
}

public class MyNode extends Node<Integer> {
    public MyNode(Integer data) { super(data); }

    public void setData(Integer data) {
        System.out.println("MyNode.setData");
        super.setData(data);
    }
}
```

After type erasure, the Node and MyNode classes become:

```
public class Node {

    public Object data;

    public Node(Object data) { this.data = data; }

    public void setData(Object data) {
        System.out.println("Node.setData");
        this.data = data;
    }
}

public class MyNode extends Node {

    public MyNode(Integer data) { super(data); }

    public void setData(Integer data) {
        System.out.println("MyNode.setData");
        super.setData(data);
    }
}
```

After type erasure the `Node` method becomes `setData(Object)` and `MyNode` method becomes `setData(Integer)`.

Why doesn't the `MyNode` method become `setData(Object)`?  Why does `Integer` not get erased?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why does the MyNode method not become setData(Object)? Why does "Integer" not be erased?

`MyNode`'s `setData` is defined as :

```
public void setData(Integer data)
```

i.e. it has no generic type parameters. Therefore there is nothing to be erased. The `data` argument remains `Integer`.

Comment: you're right. Only Node class has a generic type parameter. Thanks.